# stop systemctl printing control characters?

Tags: systemd, systemctl

Systemd likes to use control codes to insert a dot at the front of a status line:

```
$ systemctl status sshd
● sshd.service - OpenSSH server daemon
```

vis (notice the e2 97 8f before the 20 space):

```
$ systemctl status sshd | od -tx1 | head -1
0000000 e2 97 8f 20 73 73 68 64 2e 73 65 72 76 69 63 65
```

how can I stop this and have systemd use just the ASCII character set?

Playing with TERM=dumb, LANG=C and SYSTEMD_COLORS=false just change the dot's colour, and:

```
systemctl | strings
```

feels like a hack.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not a control character per se, just a fancy Unicode glyph ([U+25CF Black Circle](https://unicode-table.com/en/25CF/)). It depends on the locale if `systemctl` uses it. Tell it that you don't have a Unicode locale, and you get the ASCII asterisk instead:

```
$ LC_CTYPE=C systemctl status sshd
* ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since...
```

Or `LC_ALL=C` for the heavier hammer.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently the combination of:

```
$ LANG=C SYSTEMD_COLORS=false systemctl status sshd
* sshd.service - OpenSSH server daemon
```

does the right thing (yuck).

Comment: When I tried to do the accepted `LC_CTYPE=C` bash said `-bash: warning: setlocale: LC_CTYPE: cannot change locale (C.UTF-8)`, but your suggestion did the trick!

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get the locale (`LC_CTYPE`, `LC_ALL`) change to work, but this did:

```bash
export PAGER=cat
systemctl status myservice
```